# Cocoa: using binding to get the entity key

Tags: cocoa

I bind entities and a table with arrayController. the entity has name and id, but the table only display the name, how to can I get the id of a entity when I select a item in the table.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the array controller's selection `[arrayController selection]`, cast it to your entity class, and ask it for its ID.